# Add / remove logfiles during runtime in NLog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I'm writing a small file conversion utility. Files get automatically converted when they are dropped into a directory.

I'm using NLog for logging. Besides a central log file which is configured using *NLog.conf* (and which receives all messages generated), I'd like to create one additional log file for each input file, having a similar name and containing all log messages written during the conversion process.

Unfortunately I seem to be unable to find out how to properly add a new file target together with the appropriate rule during runtime. I want all `Logger` objects to write to the new log file during the conversion process.

I tried something like

```
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget();
logfile.FileName = fileName + ".log";
logfile.KeepFileOpen = true;
logfile.Initialize();
var rule = new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", logfile);
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
//
// Proceed with converting file
//
logfile.Flush();
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(rule);
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

But no log file was created.

What did I wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The second post on this thread led me to the solution: 
http://nlog-project.org/forum.html#nabble-td1685349

You have to get the current NLog configuration, make changes to this LoggingConfiguration object, then assign it back to LogManager.Configuration.

This is the code I used:

```
LoggingConfiguration config = LogManager.Configuration;

var logFile = new FileTarget();
config.AddTarget("file", logFile);

logFile.FileName = fileName + ".log";
logFile.Layout = "${date} | ${message}";

var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, logFile);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

LogManager.Configuration = config;

logger.Info("File converted!");
```

Comment: The line with the reassignment is very important:
LogManager.Configuration = config;

Comment: To clarify

**The line with the reassignment is very important: LogManager.Configuration = config;**

This is true because of the way NLog has written the getters and setters for the Configuration property. It's not pretty, but it has to be set again with a changed object; you can't change the property directly.

Comment: I had to reassign the logger variable at the end to get this to work:
    logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

Comment: very clear solution, thanks. I prefer giving filename directly to FileTarget.

`string filename = string.Format("C:\\LogFile-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);
var logFile = new FileTarget(filename);
config.AddTarget(logFile);`

could also be a shorter usage.

Comment: If you'd prefer cleaner c# code (e.g. avoid answering uncomfortable questions of why a class reference is being copied back onto itself to invoke a 'magic' property setter), then replace **LogManager.Configuration = config;** with **LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();**

Comment: @aozan88
new FileTarget(filename) sets the name of the target, not the fileName.

Comment: @Alex Fainshtein wow, that was a very important one for me in order to add multiple file targets. If I don't set the name FileTargets with no name are replaced.