# NLog: Generate configurations at runtime from template

Tags: c#, nlog, nlog.config

I'm trying to generate targets & logger at runtime, based on another target. Let's assume that I have a functionnal `Foo` logger: I'd like to generate separate rules for `Foo.1`, `Foo.2`, etc etc, but I can't know what will be the last logger I'll have to create (thus, I can't define them declaratively).

So far, I did something like this:

```
public GetNewClonedLogger(int fooId)
{
    var config = NLog.LogManager.Configuration;
    var newFooName = $"Foo.{fooId}";
    FileTarget baseTarget = NLog.LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<FileTarget>("Foo");

    // Copy the base target
    var newTarget = new FileTarget(newFooName)
    {
        Layout = baseTarget.Layout,
        CreateDirs = true,
        FileName = baseTarget .FileName.ToString().Replace("${var:filename}", newFooName),
        ArchiveAboveSize = baseTarget.ArchiveAboveSize,
        BufferSize = baseTarget.BufferSize,
        ArchiveFileName = baseTarget.ArchiveFileName,
        MaxArchiveFiles = baseTarget.MaxArchiveFiles,
        ArchiveDateFormat = baseTarget.ArchiveDateFormat,
        ArchiveEvery = baseTarget.ArchiveEvery,
        FileAttributes = baseTarget.FileAttributes,
        KeepFileOpen = baseTarget.KeepFileOpen,
        ArchiveNumbering = baseTarget.ArchiveNumbering,
    };

    // Add configs & flush
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(newTarget);
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration.AddRuleForAllLevels(newTarget, newFooName);

    // I tried every combinations of the following, without success
    NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Reload();

    NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(newFooName);
}
```

This function returns a logger, that seems OK on every points: the target name is OK, the filename is OK, the `NLog.LogManager.Configuration` has a new rule with the correct name (`Foo.1`, `Foo.2`, ...), and so are `AllTargets`. But when I log using the returned logger, no file is created, and it is exacly like nothing happened at all....

I've tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516242/add-remove-logfiles-during-runtime-in-nlog), without success.... What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think we can get this working, but I doubt if you really want this. What is the case this is needed for? A lot of properties of the targets are templatable, so most of the time no dynamic rules and targets are needed.

Comment: Please also note that changing (global) config isn't threadsafe.

Comment: I have to merge the template configuration with some other sources (such as database-sourced config, for example). We are aware about the thread-unsafe aspect of this approach, so we implemented our actual logger generation using `lock` keywords where required. Also, I solved the problem (see below), but thank you for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was a really silly error, as this may work as I expected. The problem was that `baseTarget.FileName` is a `Layout` object, and the stringification using `.ToString()` made bad conversions, by adding quotes to the output (`'C:\...'`). Thus, NLog threw errors, that were partially silented by NLog config & quite hard to understand anyway. I fixed it by checking if `baseTarget.FileName` is a `SimpleLayout` (the only class I had to handle in my case), then retrieve the `OriginalText` out from that layout. Then, it worked like a charm.